# Calculating (A pow B) mod M for very large A and B (stored in string)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Link to the problem:
https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/rhezo-and-big-power/description/
I saw the best submission in which the person calculated A%M (just like how we do on paper), and B%(M-1); then these two came in Integer range and he did log(n) approach to find m^n % M?
I can't really understand why would he do B%(M-1).

Comment: How did he manage to store such a large value of B.

Answer (score 2):

According to Fermat's little theorem,

```
a^(p-1) mod p = 1, When p is prime.
```

From this, As of the problem, M is prime, we can express A^B mod M as following,

```
A^B mod M = ( A^(M-1) * A^(M-1) *.......* A^(M-1) * A^(x) ) mod M
```

Where `x is B mod M-1 and A ^ (M-1) continues B/(M-1) times`

Now, From Fermat's Little theorem, `A ^ (M-1) mod M = 1.`

Hence,

```
A^B mod M = ( 1 * 1 * ....... * 1 * A^(x) ) mod M
```

This is why, we mod B with M-1